# How To Run Report - Which User Used Specific Email Templates?

Tags: email, reporting, email-template

We have lot email templates in our system. Do we have any mechanism to identify user used by email templates?

Answer (score 2):

The basic EmailTemplate only tracks how many times a template was used, and when it was used. Using the [EventLogFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm), you should be able to parse out who was using a particular template. Unfortunately, this is a paid service, *and* it requires parsing the data offline (e.g. you won't be able to build reports in the UI for this).

Realistically, if you're just looking to find old templates to clean up, you can query them by usage in the Developer Console:

```
select lastuseddate, timesused, name, folder.name from emailtemplate
```